# Embed QR Code in a Mail Merge Word Document with API call

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, mailmerge, word-addins

I have the follwoing problem:
Our client has a Microsoft Word Mail Merge Template. We have an API that takes an address and returns a link that provides the recipient of this address with access to our website. Now I want to include the QR Code into the template. However, I am not sure how or when to call the our API.

The API can only see the addresses not other fields of the Mail Merge. We do not know what the Data Source of the Mail Merge is (database or excel ...). Therefore, I assumed that the only way to call the APIwas from inside Word.

My first attempt was to create a Word Add-In. However, it seems that the Javascript API is not able to access the Mail Merge Data Source.

I am currently trying the C# Word Interops API to extract the address data, but I am not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: So why not simply insert a MergeBarcode field at the appropriate location in the mailmerge main document referencing the relevant data field in your data source? No C# code required. See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-mergebarcode-812fc43f-cb53-4782-8f9f-290ed08d34f3

Comment: @macropod The link does not yet exist in the data source but should be generated from the address through the API. I do not have access to the data source.

Comment: Just to be sure I've understood, (1) you need to get the address that is coming in from the data source, and then you want to generate a barcode that has information that is not actually in the address and insert it into the generated document. (2) are these documents being saved to disk or being emailed? (3) can your API be called via an http: address (cf. some of the QR code generators out there), and (4), have you looked at using MailMerge events to do per-document processing?

Comment: @markimark If it's the address you want barcoded, then that is the relevant field in the datasource. The mailmerge main document cannot but have access to the datasource.

Comment: @jonsson 
(1) yes 
(2) document should be saved to disk
(3) the API returns a json containing a link for a specific address. I want to show the link as an QR Code with { DisplayBarcode { Mergefield Link } QR } (assuming I now have a mergfield "Link")
(4) No not yet and I did not find anything with a quick google search. Can you share a link?

Comment: @macropod I have access to the address yes, but the link does not yet exist. I want to show the link as an qr code.

Comment: Also, does the address data always come from a single field in the data source? Or could it actually come from multiple fields, or be constructed in the Mailmerge main document using an ADDRESSBLOCK field?

Comment: Re. 4, the events themselves are documented around here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.mailmergebeforerecordmerge but most of the examples are VBA (or VB.NET), or using VSTO which is a different thing altogether. Re. 3 I don't think you will be able to do that because you would have to be able to identify the record in the data source and update it before the merge. Perhaps better to  insert the text you need directly into  the DISPLAYBARCODE field.

Comment: Incidentally, the Mailmerge events are not known for their reliability. Only use them if you cannot use code that performs one merge for each record in the data source.